# How i can transpose criteria column and repeat the column A in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to transpose column criteria B C D E and column A repeat in every criteria.
I don't know the query. please help me.
This the link google sheets sample i made, my original data was thousand.
thank you

1wGH-MGpuDE_vwRVuiWuNywRMIvPdF7OaFeLxpgR5wK0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed the following formula into a new sheet ("Erik Help"), cell A9:

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A3&"\"&B1:E1&"\"&B2:E3),"\",1,0))
```

NOTE: FLATTEN is not yet an official Google Sheets function. I recommend you do the following, once the formula creates the new layout:

1.) Select the entire new data range created by the formula and hit Ctrl-C to copy it to clipboard.

2.) With the range still selected, hit Ctrl-Alt-V ("Paste Special").

3.) A tiny clipboard icon will appear screen lower right. Click it and choose "Paste values only."

This will convert the formula-generated data to an in-place hard copy of the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, that's mean a lots for me. GBU

Comment: Great! If this addresses the issue in your post to your satisfaction, please take a moment to mark the answer as "Best Answer." It signals to others that this issue is resolved, and it will help future information seekers such as yourself to find answers to their own questions more quickly.

Comment: Hi, if there any way to show only the criteria with value?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "criteria with value"? Please show on your sheet the desired result and leave notification here when you have done that.

Comment: Hi, i have update the sheets, i want the blank cell doesn't appear. Can we use if it's not null "" it will appear, something like that.

Comment: See CrossTab!G1

Comment: thank you so much Erik for helping.

Comment: Hallo Erik, 
I have another question. i have code it's a plain text format, but when i flatten it, it's change into random code (in plain text format) and it's appear in automatic format (but in Fx bar its change into date), can you help me? thank you before

Comment: I have changed the formula in your sheet. Intermediate steps were trying to interpret your hyphenated strings as month-year dates; so I SUBSTITEd the hyphen at the root with a rocket symbol (could have been anything you would never use), then SUBSTITUTEd it back for the hyphen after the SPLIT. From here, please start a new thread with new questions so that future users can benefit. Comments are not designed to be used this way.

Comment: thank you Erik for helping, i have create the new question. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/146277/how-to-show-plain-text-format-in-flatten-query

Comment: Hi Erik, in my case i need to show date too, and it replace with subtitute query, and the number value can't to sum because it text

Answer (score 0):

See your file sheet "test2" cell **G1**.

Formula consists of 3 parts for each column.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",REPT(A2:A&",", COUNTA($B$1:$E$1))), ",")))
```

These part of formula repeat values from column A N times, where N is number of columns with data in your initial table (3 in example), thus you can adjust it to table size changing this part COUNTA($B$1:$E$1).

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",",$B$1:$E$1&","),COUNTA(A2:A)),",")))
```

this formula repeats headers of initial table N times, where N is number of rows in your data. Also can be adjusted for different tables by changing $B$1:$E$1 - headers range.

```
ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(B2:E&","),",")))
```

Last part transforms values from table into single column. Also can be adjusted for different tables by changing B2:E.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, that's mean a lots for me. GBU